# Why is OTG not working on Android 11?

Tags: usb

[image]

I have a Samsung Android 11 device and I can't open the usb via OTG and I think the problem is with the Android 11 update. Is there a solution?

Comment: The USB mode shown on your screen shot is not OTG, instead it is client mode like if you are connected to a PC.

Comment: I am facing same problem, OTG is not working in Samsung M31 after android 11 update.